# Can't select multiple checkboxes in while loop

Tags: php, checkbox, checkboxlist

After using while loop,I only select first checkbox but  I can't select multiple checkboxes in page. Plz solve this issue.

```
$get=mysqli_query($con,"select * from subjects where cour_id='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($get))
    {
        ?>
        <div class="be-checkbox">
        <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="<?php echo $data['sub_name'];?>">
        <label for="check"><?php echo $data['sub_name'];?></label>
        </div>
       <?php
    }
```

Comment: change checkbox name `name="chk[<?php echo $data['sub_id']; ?>]"` to can select many checkboxes

Comment: it not works...– Jacek B Budzynski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$get=mysqli_query($con,"select * from subjects where cour_id='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($get))
    {
        ?>
        <div class="be-checkbox">
        <input id="check<?php echo $data['id'];?" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="<?php echo $data['sub_name'];?>">
        <label for="check<?php echo $data['sub_name'];?"><?php echo $data['sub_name'];?></label>
        </div>
       <?php
    }
```

Make unique your input ids. Change id if your query doesn't have an id field. Just use something unique. I also recommend you to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) library of PHP instead of `mysqli_query`. It provides an OOP way to connect your database and it makes your queries more secure.

Comment: ohh....I am so stupid bcz I can't do this simple thing....by the way thank u so much....it works...